# Simulating a random process with correlation structure $e^{-|t-s|}$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-calculus, simulation

Consider a random process $X_t$ such that $$dX_t\sim N(0,dt)$$ and $$\operatorname{corr}(dX_t,dX_s)=e^{-k|t-s|}.$$
This question is probably trivial but how can I simulate the path path of $X_t$? Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I can't help wondering whether what you actually want is $\operatorname{corr}(X_t,X_s)$ rather than $\operatorname{corr}(dX_t,dX_s).$ 
Maybe I'll look at this again later. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy yes, that was a mistake on my end. I will just leave it this way since there is already an answer below. But if you have time, please share your thoughts on $corr(X_t,X_s)$

Comment: @Not_a_topologist As your question changed to $corr(X_t,X_s) = ...$, I added a second case for this new question which a little simpler compared to the initial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us construct a time grid $0=t_0<t_1 < t_2 <\cdots<t_n =T$ with $t_k=k\,\Delta t$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$ and $\Delta t = \frac{T}{n}$.

**Case 1:** $corr(dX_t,dX_s) = e^{-k|t-s|}$
. The $n$ gaussian variables $\{(X_{t_k}-X_{t_{k-1}}) \}_{k=1,\ldots,n}$ follow the multivariate normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}_n,\mathbf{\Sigma})$ with the covariance matrix $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ defined by
$$\Sigma_{ij} = e^{-k|i-j|\Delta t} \, \Delta t$$

First, you generate these random vectors $\mathbf{W}$ following  $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}_n,\mathbb{I}_{n\times n})$ and calculate the square root matrix $\mathbf{\Sigma}^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Then the vector $\mathbf{Y}$ defined by $Y_k = X_{t_k}-X_{t_{k-1}}$ for $k = 1,...,n$ can be calculated as
$$\mathbf{Y}= \mathbf{\Sigma}^{\frac{1}{2}}\mathbf{W}$$

After obtaining the vector $\mathbf{Y}$, the path $X_t$ can be computed as
$$X_{t_k} = X_{t_{k-1}}+Y_{k}$$

---

**Case 2:** $corr(X_t,X_s) = e^{-k|t-s|}\implies Cov(X_t,X_s)=e^{-k|t-s|}\sqrt{ts} $$\implies Cov(X_{t_i},X_{t_j})=e^{-k|i-j|\Delta t}\sqrt{ij}\Delta t$

This case is easier, The $n$ gaussian variables $\{X_{t_k}\}_{k=1,\ldots,n}$ follow the multivariate normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}_n,\mathbf{\Sigma'})$ with the covariance matrix $\mathbf{\Sigma'}$ defined by
$$\Sigma'_{ij} = e^{-k|i-j|\Delta t}\sqrt{ij}\Delta t$$

First, you generate these random vectors $\mathbf{W}$ following  $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}_n,\mathbb{I}_{n\times n})$ and calculate the square root matrix $\mathbf{\Sigma'}^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Then the vector $\mathbf{X}$ can be calculated as
$$\mathbf{X}= \mathbf{\Sigma'}^{\frac{1}{2}}\mathbf{W}$$

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. This makes sense.

Comment: Do you mean $\Sigma_{ij}=e^{-k|i-j|}(t_i-t_j)?$. Is the $dt$ in the exponent a typo?

Comment: @Not_a_topologist No, I really want to write 
$$\Sigma_{ij} = e^{-k|i-j|dt}dt$$
Indeed, the covariance is equal to $\Sigma_{ij}  = Corr * \sqrt{ V(X_{t_i}-X_{t_{i-1}}) } * \sqrt{ V(X_{t_j}-X_{t_{j-1}}) }$ and the two standard deviations are equal to $\sqrt{dt}$, hence
$$\Sigma_{ij}  = Corr * dt  $$

Comment: I think $Var(X_t-X_s)=t-s.$

Comment: @Not_a_topologist but with $t = t_i$ , $s = t_{i-1}$, you will have $V(X_t-X_s) = \Delta t$

Comment: Sure it should be $dt$ and not $\Delta t$

Comment: To be more precise I think something like $\Sigma_{i,j}=e^{-k|\Delta_i-\Delta_j|}\sqrt{\Delta_i}\sqrt{\Delta_j}$ is more accurate

Comment: @Not_a_topologist In fact, it's all about notation. But in general, we ussually denote $t_i -t_{i-1}$ by $\Delta t$ in discrete time. So, I changed the notation from $dt$ to $\Delta t$. In continuous time, we use $dt$.

Comment: @Not_a_topologist $\Delta_i := t_i -t_{i-1} =t_j -t_{j-1} =:  \Delta_j$ and both are equal to $\Delta t = \frac{T}{n}$